# what is fadingEdgeLength attribute meant for?

Tags: android, xml

what is the use of **android:fadingEdgeLength** attribute meant for. i have seen this attribute for some views and wigdets in android project's xml

Comment: @KristiyanVarbanov ofcourse i did try google but didnt find any useful answer or explanation...even explanation provided by android docs is not understandable by me...i wanted i wanted answer from somone who has hands experience on it so that i know where is it used exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used for adjusting the length of the fading edge that you see when you scroll. You can see the effects on the edges of the screen in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the android official documentation:

> Defines the length of the fading edges.
>
> Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

The `fadingEdgeLength`manages the size of fading shown at edges of a View.
For instance, a ScrollView or a ListView.
You can combine threquiresFadingEdge to show it `horizontal`ly or `vertical`ly or `none` (the latter, in order not to show any).